# Computing a color in a good range ("different enough" from other color) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, colors, rgb, hsv, hsl

I'm working on an open source project that uses a lot of key=value tags, and represents them in a HTML UI with labels that show the value as text, and deterministically generates a color for the foreground text based on the key ([code here](https://github.com/vimeo/graph-explorer/blob/e9da5096adbda3f9173865685089dbe09f4625b1/assets/js/graph-explorer.js#L133)). To get an idea how this looks like, check the screenshot @ https://raw.github.com/vimeo/graph-explorer/master/screenshots/screenshot.png; the tag legend on the right shows the tag key strings and which colors they map to.
For now, I've left the background of all labels RGB #333, because that seems to look about right on the dark background of the page.

For some keys, this goes a little wrong, as you may expect. For example 
"status" gives #7b0065 which is a dark purple, the contrast with the background is not high enough.

I tried [Automatically change text color to assure readability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600295/automatically-change-text-color-to-assure-readability/9601429#9601429) to compute the inverse color for the background, but:

1. All the different background colors make for a very ugly page.
2. Text is often still unreadable (often even more so, it looks like)

So instead of getting the inverse color, maybe it's better to compute a color that "stays away" from a given color, I.e. From the background color #333.

Maybe we can get the "distance" between a given color and the background, and if too close, modify the key a little and try again. Or, a better idea?

[Checking if a color is in a specific range of colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333491/checking-if-a-color-is-in-a-specific-range-of-colors) looks interesting but it's for ruby and also seems to use improper math (no HSL/HSV).

Comment: It's much easier if you work in the HSL colorspace.  You just go around the circle in 120 degree increments, and drop the L value every time you circle around.

Comment: Pointy is right in that it'll be much easier than RGB, but HSL doesn't account for perceptual brightness... so you will see certain colors *appear* much darker at the same L. I recommend checking out [HUSL](http://boronine.com/husl/) for this. Also, I wrote [a library](https://github.com/nluqo/autumn) that generates colors deterministically and if you know your background color, you can establish ranges of lightness to stay within to maximize readability.